# Incidentally removed lightdm - how to get it back?

Tags: lightdm

I have incidentally removed lightdm,
by `sudo apt-get purge lightdm`.
Now I am not seeing login screen when starting the computer.
(only black background.. nothing else)

How to restore/install it back?
I am using ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Update: I am trying to chroot from liveUSB, but I am getting:

```
chroot: failed to run command /bin/bash: No such file or directory
```

How to fix it?

Comment: Problem is after pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 nothing has happened.

Answer (score 1):

First, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> which should bring up a login prompt.

Login, and then

```
sudo -i
apt-get install lightdm
```

Once that completes, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> should bring you to a now working `lightdm`.

Comment: After pressing Ctrl-Alt-F1 nothing has happened.

Comment: Press the control key and the alt key, hold them. Now press <F1>. Release all keys.

Comment: It works normally, but in this case no :(

Comment: Do you have `sshd` running?

Comment: I do not know, how to determine that?

Comment: If you didn't install it the answer is probably no. And you're pressing the ctrl-alt-f1 sequence - all three simultaneously?

Comment: Yes.. but I have tryied it also as you mentioned above. And please note update to my original post (about chroot)